# Can't understand this solution to the combinatorics problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, combinations

```
You have 3 literature books, 2 computer books, and 1 math book.
How many ways can books be sorted on a shelf 
if the books of literature and those of mathematics are all close together?
```

The right answer: $3!3!2!$

my answer: $3 \cdot 4!2!$ because I have 4(=3+1) elements to order, so $4!$ and the other 2 books to order so $2!$, all multiplied by 3 because I have 3 ways to sort this books.

$$\_ \ \_ \ I \ I \ I \ I$$
$$\_ \ I \ I \ I \ I \ \_$$
$$I \ I \ I \ I \ \_ \ \_$$
Why I'm wrong?

Comment: Nothing wrong with your working. _Close together_ should not mean the math book has to be in one of the two places between literature books. That is what seems to be the book solution.

Comment: You and the problem giver have a different understanding of close together it looks like. Personally I think your understanding makes sense all told.

Comment: The question is not clear. Why is it using the plural for math books if there is only one? What does close together mean? Does it apply to the groups of 3 literature books and that of 1 math book separately, or does it mean all 4 remain close together? I probably can find interpretations to justify both answers, and maybe others as well.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I think all 4

Comment: @Marc van Leeuwen This is a new sort of exercise. The question and answer are given, and the exercise is to find some meaning for the question that makes the answer correct. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the problem meant to say that all the literature books must be in one group, and also all the computer books (rather than the math books) must be in one group. It certainly seems like something like that must have been intended, since -- as others noted in the comments -- the "close together" constraint seems meaningless for a single book.

Under this interpretation, we'd have $3!$ ways to arrange the literature books among themselves and $2!$ ways to arrange the computer books. (If we're being a bit cheeky, we could also observe that there's just $1! = 1$ way to arrange the single math book.) Then we have $3!$ ways to arrange the groups of Literature, Computers, and Math, yielding $3!3!2!$ arrangements, as claimed.